# Gerando gráficos com hightchart, PHP, MYSQL e Angular JS

Tags: php, angularjs

Estou tentando gerar gráficos de forma dinâmica com as tecnologias (PHP, MYSQL, AngularJS).

Este é o meu código em PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT descricao, estoque from `alimentos`";

Transaction::open("mysql");
$conn = Transaction::get();         
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result){
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        $data[] = array($row->descricao, $row->estoque);                    
    }
            return json_encode($data);              
}
```

Obs: Ao inspecionar pelo firebug o retorno do código PHP é:

```
[["frango","200.000"],["Bacon","15.000"],["Calabresa","100.000"],["Carne Moida","20.000"]]
```

---

Este é o meu código Angular JS

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app').controller('painelController', function($scope, $http, $window, $location){
    //Define metodos para graficos
    $scope.chartAlimentos = function(){
        $http.post(url + 'server/modulos/materia_prima/alimentos.php', {action:'loadChart'}).success(function(response){                                    
            //Gera o grafico na view            
            $('#chart-alimentos').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Estoque atual' 
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '<b>Percentual</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            format: '{point.name}: <b>{point.y} Kg</b>',
                            style: {
                                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                            },
                            showInLegend: true
                        }
                    }               
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    data: [ response ]
                }],
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                }, 
                exporting: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            });         

        });
    }

});
```

Obs: Vi em alguns tutoriais que o pessoal pede pra utilizar o seguinte o código no script do gráfico:

```
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    data: ['<?php echo join(',',$sjon) ?>' ]
}],
```

Mas no meu caso não é possível devido a separação de códigos cliente e servidor

E por último o erro que ocorre é que o gráfico não renderiza corretamente. Não entendo o erro pois se eu copiar e colar o retorno do php que descrivi acima funciona normalmente

Answer (score 1):

Ai pessoal consegui resolver o problema, pelo que percebi estava passando os valores corretos mas um pequeno detalhe no meu codigo PHP fez toda a diferença, como ei estava passando uma cadeia de caracteres strings para o hightchart e ele estava esperando valores inteiros usei a função (int) do php para converter em inteiro um array, ficou assim

```
        if($result){
            while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                $data[] = array("{$row->descricao}", (int)$row->estoque);                   
            }
            return json_encode($data);

            //Exemplo saída para grafico hightchart tipo PIE valores strings com aspas duplas, valores inteiros sem aspas
            //ex.: '[["frango",15.000],["Calabresa",70.000],["Bacon",200.000]]';                
        }    insira o código aqui
```

Um grande abraço a todos....

Comment: Abraço. Tudo de bom pra você e sua família.